# How can I install Tensorflow GPU with latest version of CUDA and cuDNN

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorflow-lite

Installing TensorFlow for object detection is annoying sometimes, especially when wired errors happen after starting one's own object detection project by finetuning pre-trained model.

How to install latest Tensorflow GPU support and latest CUDA/CUDNN without any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### To install tensorflow-gpu object detection api on Ubuntu 16.04

#### upgrade system

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade
```

#### install basic packages

```
sudo apt-get install vim curl python-dev gnupg-curl python-tk git

curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py

sudo -H python get-pip.py
```

#### install tensorflow-gpu (tensorflow version=1.14)

```
sudo -H pip install tensorflow-gpu
```

#### install CUDA (Final CUDA version = 10.1)

```
// Please turn off your secure boot from BIOS

sudo apt-get install gnupg-curl

// Here we install version 10.0 to avoid other issues. Later we can upgrade it to version 10.1
wget https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604_10.0.130-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-key adv --fetch-keys https://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/7fa2af80.pub

sudo apt-get update

wget http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/machine-learning/repos/ubuntu1604/x86_64/nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt install ./nvidia-machine-learning-repo-ubuntu1604_1.0.0-1_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get update
```

#### install cuDNN (cuDNN version = 7.6.3.30-1, compatible to CUDA 10.1)

```
sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends cuda-10-0

// restart your computer here

nvidia-smi.

sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends libcudnn7=7.6.3.30-1+cuda10.0 libcudnn7-dev=7.6.3.30-1+cuda10.0

sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends libnvinfer5=5.1.5-1+cuda10.0 libnvinfer-dev=5.1.5-1+cuda10.0

sudo apt-get update

// this upgrade command will upgrade your CUDA to version 10.1
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

#### install Tensorflow object detection api

```
sudo -H pip install Cython

sudo -H pip install contextlib2

sudo -H pip install pillow

sudo -H pip install lxml

sudo -H pip install jupyter

sudo -H pip install matplotlib


mkdir tensorflow
cd tensorflow
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models

// install protocbuf version 3.0.0
wget -O protobuf.zip https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.0.0/protoc-3.0.0-linux-x86_64.zip
unzip protobuf.zip
sudo cp ./bin/protoc /bin/
sudo cp -r ./include/google /usr/local/include/
cd tensorflow/models/research
protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.

git clone https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git
cd cocoapi/PythonAPI
make
cp -r pycocotools <path_to_tensorflow>/models/research/
```

#### Export Environment

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:~/tensorflow/models/research:~/tensorflow/models/research/object_detection/slim
```

#### Other

```
If we install CUDA 10.1 it may have a compatibility issue that libxxxx.so.10.0 is not found when you start training your project.

To solve them:

a. sudo ln -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcublas.so.10.1 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcublas.so.10.0

b. sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcudart.so.10.1 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcudart.so.10.0

c. sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcufft.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcufft.so.10.0

d. sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcurand.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcurand.so.10.0

e. sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcusolver.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcusolver.so.10.0

f. sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcusparse.so.10 /usr/local/cuda-10.1/lib64/libcusparse.so.10.0
```

#### All Set